# Making sure JVM does not optimize

Tags: java, jvm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to make sure no jvm and compiler optimization occures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242405/how-to-make-sure-no-jvm-and-compiler-optimization-occures)

I am trying to compare a bunch of different path finding algorithms all implemented using java, I would like to time these but I need to make sure that JVM does not do any sort of optimization behind my back?

Answer (score 4):

I know what you're thinking -- optimization skews the results if one algorithm can be optimized more efficiently than another.  But let me suggest that optimization is part of the answer.  If I have two path finding algorithms, and then why wouldn't I favour the one that lends itself to better compiler optimizations in the environment in which it will be executing?  Designing an algorithm that optimizes better is part of designing a better algorithm, isn't it?

I know I'm not really answering your question, but I *am* suggesting that the effects of optimization is part of the timing results you are trying to meaure.

Comment: The problem is if you're trying to compare the "root" algorithm itself, the optimization may skew the results. IRL, I totally agree, but for research purposes, you'd want to remove as many influences as possible.

Answer (score 0):

To run your Java program in 100% interpreted mode, you can specify `-Xint` on your command line.  To make the JIT behaive more deterministically, use the -Xbatch flag.

```
-Xbatch
```

> Disable background compilation. Normally the VM will compile the
>   method as a background task, running the method in interpreter mode
>   until the background compilation is finished. The -Xbatch flag
>   disables background compilation so that compilation of all methods
>   proceeds as a foreground task until completed.

In principal, I agree with Steve J's response above - however - you may wish to collect information on unoptimized code for comparison.