# Does Java JIT compiler remove method's call without side effects?

Tags: java, jit

I have a simple method to check if input string is valid xpath

```
private boolean isXpath(String value) {
    boolean isXpath = true;
    try {
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        xpath.compile(value);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        isXpath = false;
    }
    return isXpath;
}
```

Can I be sure that JIT compiler won't remove code inside `try` block, because of it has no side effects? Or it has (possible exception)?

Comment: If you want to force the compiler _not_ to perform any optimisations, look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242405/how-to-make-sure-no-jvm-and-compiler-optimization-occurs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dead Code Eliminatino is not just about side-effects, but also about using the result of computation. Since your method returns `isXpath`, which cannot be derived without executing the `try` block, it is impossible for the JIT compiler to eliminate it.

Comment: I wouldn't say impossible: If the JIT inlines `XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath()` and due to constant propagation and similar optimisations can deduce that the code either always throws an exception or never, it could then simplify the whole method to `return CONST`. In practice that's so exceedingly unlikely that it's reasonable to call that impossible I agree.

Comment: Only under the assumption that no string is a valid XPath or all of them are, and the compiler can prove that. Clearly not applicable here.

Comment: Well, there _is_ this edge case of a call site that uses a string constant. Then it would be theoretically possible to effectively memoize the return value of the call.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of passing say null in there, which I'm assuming would throw a NRE.